# MTT assay data pre-processing

Tags: cell-culture, biostatistics, data

I was handed [MTT assay](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/US/en/technical-documents/protocol/cell-culture-and-cell-culture-analysis/cell-counting-and-health-analysis/cell-proliferation-kit-i-mtt) data, consisting of drug doses and raw OD scores. The drug treatments were performed three separate times, each followed by MTT assay.

I applied some non-linear mixed-level dose-response modeling (log-logistic model) to the data and generated dose-response curves, ED50, etc.

I got the feedback that I first needed to subtract mean blank values of each plate from each OD on a plate, then divide the blank-subtracted values by the mean blank-subtracted value for dose = 0, again on each plate. THEN the PI wanted me to "propagate error" for the modeling.

What is the function of the division-by-zero-dose mean OD? Will that suppress plate-to-plate variation, which  means any aggregate model will be less trustworthy? I was told that all that pre-processing was the standard procedure "in the field". Is this the case? If so, why is it "standard procedure"?

If one assigns random effects to each plate, one can account for plate-to-plate variation without suppressing it, after all.

Comment: I’m not sure the poster is expecting an answer to this question, so why it has been edited escapes me. He would have been well advised to define MTT, as “mean transit time” seems hardly appropriate, but it’s too late now, I imagine.